# Loading image info from external txt file and displaying in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a Javascript function load information for an image from an external text file, and display the image on my WordPress site. I found some code online to load and parse an external text file.

I haven't been successful in getting it to work though.

I set up a separate html test page, but that's not working either.

I'm trying to have the site load that js file, and output the image, using this code in the mmusic div:

```
document.write('<a href="' + AdLinkPath[0] + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + AdFilePath[0] + '" width="' + AdWidth[0] + '" height="' + AdHeight[0] + '"/></a>');
```

I tried the same code in the test.html file, and I haven't been able to get it to work.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.write` statement is occurring before the AJAX response is received. If you move that statement directly after the four `return` statements it should solve your problem.

Comment: Oops - I had tried adding in the return lines, but it didn't seem to help, and I accidentally left them in there.
And even if that works, I still need to get it working with the js function and the document.write function separately, on the main site...

Comment: @IsaacL - Your document.write **must** be called from somewhere within your onreadystatechange function, otherwise it will always happen before a response is received. If you'd like you could just wrap the document.write portion in a function, and call that function at the end of the onreadystatechange. It really doesn't matter how you implement it, that's just what has to be done.

Comment: Instead of using document.write, use `document.getElementById('adContainer').innerHTML = 'string';` - Then in the main site just make sure whatever DIV (or another element where you'll place the ad) has an ID of "adContainer". Then update the 'string' part there to be the contents of the document.write.

Comment: In your ads.js file you replace the document.write line with that one (updating the string it writes). And in the main site code you'll want to add a container element for the ad to appear in (or you can create one on-the-fly and append it to another element), just make sure the ID in the getElementById matches the ID of the container element you create.

Comment: Sure, you can actually use almost any other kind of inline or block element (such as a SPAN or LI tag), and as long as it has an ID that matches it should work fine.

Comment: As long as there's no reason to make a new element on the fly, I assume this should work...
Just switched it to a SPAN within the div, which should keep things neater.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your specific problem is, but there are certainly a number of things that you could do to improve the overall design.

Firstly, are you sure that this is even something that you want to do in Javascript? It seems like you are modifying a text file on your server to tell your pages which ads to serve. That's alright, but if you have the option, it would be better to do this server side. Just include the appropriate urls to the images before you send the HTML back to the users browser using PHP or a similar language if you have access to do so. This removes complexity from your code, improves page load speed, and properly displays your ads even without proper Javascript support.

If you are going to do this with AJAX, then I would highly recommend using JSON formatted data and some type of library to handle the request for you. Parsing text files presents a number of problems, and formatting data as JSON gives you a cheap way to convert it to a Javascript object. jQuery is one popular choice for doing this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

You could format your file more like:

```
{
    "img": "http://myhost/img/mm.jpg"
    "link": "http://myhost/"
    "width": "192"
    "height": "108"
}
```

Then you would need to do something like this to update the image field on your page:

```
$.getJSON("test.js", function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
        //parse the keys and values appropriately in here
    });
});
```

You also probably don't want to use document.write. This overwrites the entire content of the page. You probably want to select your image element in some way and then change its attributes. You can use jQuery selectors for this. See the section on manipulation for ways to modify the img element once you've selected it.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to be able to load the image info from an external file, possible even on an external site. I probably could do that in PHP, but I don't know how to do that...
And I don't know much AJAX/jQuery, so I'm not sure how I would do that..
Any suggestions are welcome though ;)

Comment: You're using AJAX already. Your using XMLHttpRequest() to request data asynchronously. I suggested jQuery simply because I thought it would be easier.

Comment: I'd love to use jQuery, but I don't know how to get things with that, and it's now working with AJAX (I meant that I don't know much AJAX, I just pieced things together from snippets I found online).
If someone would be willing to give me the code to get it working with jQuery, I'd use that, but I don't know enough to get working...